# MYSQL: Possible to select the nearest timestamp relative to X which is > than X. If none, then result should be the nearest that is < X?

Tags: mysql

I have a constant timestamp of say 18040986 (in my query its $readtime).

Now my table has many entries and each entry has its own timestamp.

I wanted to efficiently search to find the timestamp which is greater then the constant timestamp, but is also the nearest to that.  (In essence I am trying to find the first unread entry by a user)

Now the trick is, that say there have been no entries made then I would love to get the nearest timestamp that is less then the current timestamp (ie. the nearest old entry that has already been read)

I was hoping for help with the query to achieve that.  The basic queries I have made so far have either been highly inefficient and have slowed my server to a crawl or have been inaccurate.  The query I am using for now is this

```
                    SELECT postid 
                    FROM theposts
                    WHERE category = '$tid' AND visible='1' AND dateline > '$readtime' 
                    LIMIT 1
```

But I am worried that the above query wont actually return the next nearest postid that is greater then my readtime if for some reason my table has entries out of order one day

Comment: so your constant is a variable? Anyway, see UNION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be inclined to do this:

```
(SELECT p.postid 
 FROM theposts p
 WHERE p.category = '$tid' AND p.visible='1' AND p.dateline > '$readtime' 
 ORDER BY p.dateline
 LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT p.postid 
 FROM theposts p
 WHERE p.category = '$tid' AND p.visible='1' AND p.dateline < '$readtime' AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM theposts p
                   WHERE p.category = '$tid' AND p.visible='1' AND
                         p.dateline > '$readtime'
                  )
 ORDER BY p.dateline DESC
 LIMIT 1
)
```

For performance, you want an index on `theposts(category, visible, dateline)`.

If performance is less of an issue, the following is a simpler way to write the query:

```
 SELECT p.postid 
 FROM theposts p
 WHERE p.category = '$tid' AND p.visible='1' AND 
 ORDER BY (p.dateline > '$readtime') DESC,
          (case when p.dateline > '$readtime' then p.dateline end) ASC,
          p.dateline DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

With this version, though, I don't see how to have the `order by` use an index.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT * 
  FROM
     (
       (SELECT * FROM ints WHERE i > 8 ORDER BY i LIMIT 1)
        UNION
       (SELECT * FROM ints WHERE i < 8 ORDER BY i DESC LIMIT 1)
     ) x
 ORDER BY i DESC LIMIT 1;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 9 |
+---+
```